# Attaching space, help on visualization

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $A\subset X$ a closed subspace. $CA$ means the cone of $A$, and by $SA$ I'll denote the suspension of $A$.

I need to prove that

> $$ \left( \left( (X \cup CA) \cup CX \right) \cup C(X \cup CA) \right)/ C(X \cup CA)  \approx SX$$

I figured out that $((X \cup CA) \cup CX )/ CX \approx SA$ but for the first I can't even write down a sketch to help understanding the situation.

Can someone gives some advice about how to visualize the space in exam? I made some sketches for two easy cases, (where X and A are two concentric circles, or X is a disk and A a circle) but I can't generalize it an a satisfying way

Comment: It seems clear that $(((X ∪ CA) ∪ CX) ∪ C(X ∪ CA)) / C(X ∪ CA) \approx CX / X$. The parts you added are later glued to a point so you actually didn't have to add them. I visualized $X$ as a line segment and $A$ as its proper subsegment.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's not correct. I imagined $CX$ as a new cone independent from $CA$. So, is $CA ⊆ CX$ or are they independent?

Comment: @user87690 I think they are independent. The author says "added later"

Comment: What author are you talking about? Do you mean someone who gave you the question you posted or the author of the first comment? Note that the second comment is continuation rather than reaction to the first one. They are both by me.

Comment: @user87690 I'm trying to filling the details of the construction of the long exact sequence in K-theory. I'm referring to hatcher's k-theory book (pag. 52-53)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first clear up the notation. Let $Y := (((X ∪ CA) ∪ CX) ∪ C(X ∪ CA))$. I assume that the meaning is such that the following hold: $X ∩ CA = A$, $CA ∩ CX = A$, $(X ∪ CA ∪ CX) ∩ C(X ∪ CA) = X ∪ CA$.

Now let's prove the following claim.

> Let $A, B ⊆ X$, $A ∩ B ≠ ∅$. Then $(A ∪ B) / B \approx A / (A ∩ B)$.

Proof: Let $q: A ∪ B \to (A ∪ B) / B$ be the quotient and $i: A \to A ∪ B$ be the inclusion. Then $q \circ i$ is onto $(A ∪ B) / B$, is injective on $A \setminus B$ whereas $A ∩ B$ is contracted to a point. So to prove the claim it remains to see that $q \circ i$ is a quotient mapping. Let $(q \circ i)^{-1}[U]$ be open in $A$. Then either is is disjoint with $B$ and so is open in $A ∪ B$ or is joint with $B$ and so $q^{-1}[U] ⊇ B$ and $q^{-1}[U] ∩ A$ is open so again $q^{-1}[U]$ is open in $A ∪ B$. In both cases by $q$ being quotient, we have that $U$ is open which we wanted.

Now we can apply the claim to get the proposition: $(X ∪ CA ∪ CX ∪ C(X ∪ CA)) / C(X ∪ CA) \approx (X ∪ CA ∪ CX) / (X ∪ CA) \approx CX / X \approx SX$.

Note that we don't need that $A$ is closed, we just need that $X$ is non-empty.